# How do I sell my Elder Scrolls?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

These Elder Scrolls are useless after the quests, and they weigh 20 each, I know after I complete the Dawnguard side of the quest I can sell them to Dexion for a disappointing 6000 gold, and I had also noticed that Urag in the Arcanium inside the college of Winterhold will take the Elder Scroll(Dragon) off your hands for 2000 gold, I have completed the Vampire side of the quest and Dexion won't take them, he just sits there saying "Imagine a world without a sun", so how do I get rid of my Sun and Blood Elder Scrolls?

Comment: If you can't drop or store them, then they're still considered quest items and the weight doesn't count against your encumbrance, regardless of the displayed weight of the item.

Comment: That's weird, I did the vampire side and Dexion took my scrolls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dexion is fixed by version 1.2.2 of the Unofficial Dawnguard Patch, which adds the dialog to sell the scrolls to him if you go with the vampire side.

See http://www.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Dawnguard%20Patch%20Version%20History.html

> Alternatively you might regard it as weird for him to buy them given he's been make a vampire thrall - in which case the behaviour is as expected.

Comment: Does that count for Xbox too?

Comment: I imagine the bugs will be the same (or the original developers might regard it as a feature), and you can't use mods with Xbox so you're stuck with the game without mods.

Comment: Pretty sure this got fixed in a more recent official patch for all platforms so you can sell the scrolls to Dexion if you sided with clan Volkihar.